# Folder.jpg not found from an UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

I develop a music player application on the universal windows platform.

In my music folder, I've some folder.jpg file (probably created by windows media player or groove music?). These files are system protected and hidden.

I would like to use folder.jpg in my app, but I cannot see them in my code.
If I try to create a folder.jpg I encouter an unauthorized exception.

```
 StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);
 StorageFile coverFile = await folder.TryGetItemAsync("folder.jpg") as StorageFile;
```

coverFile is null and if I check with the file explorer, I can see it.

How can I access this sort of files ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the *actual* exception type name and the full error message?

Comment: `StorageFolder` sounds like its an isolated storage folder.

Comment: You won't be able to access folder via path in UWP - you should use either known folders or folder picker. To access music you can use *KnownFolders.MusicLibrary*. However this won't probably help, hence I suspect that app won't have permission to read system protected and hidden files.

Comment: yes I access them by path in the music library and it works.
I agree with about system protected files, I think UWP can't access them.

Answer (score 0):

UWP Apps run in a sandboxed environment. In terms of their access to files they can access;

1) Files in their own storage folders like Local/Temp/Roaming.

2) Files in places like libraries if they have specified that they want to access that library (with the documents library being a bit of an exception).

3) Files that they are "given" by the user via means like file/folder open pickers and it's worth being aware that once an app has access to a certain file/folder then it can request to 'keep' access to that file/folder for the future.

4) There's also a capability for an app to access files in a special area shared between apps that come from the same publisher.

The idea is that this remains under the user's control so, by default, an app cannot just open a file in c:\temp or c:\users\name...\ but if the user actually gives the app access to one of those files then that's different.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers)

It can be done only you need to use FolderPicker to actually feed the path.
Explanation on how to use this can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers).

Comment: thank you,
Actually Files are in the music library. I can read all files (mp3, some picture, some text files) except these folder.jpg.  I think it 's because it has a system&hidden flag.